# Do any programming languages or package managers support coherence/confluence/global uniqueness of installed packages?

Tags: package, programming-languages, package-managers

When [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) installs packages, it produces a tree of dependencies, where each package in the tree has its own tree of dependencies. As a result, the same package may occur in the tree multiple times. When obtaining an object that is re-exported through transitive dependencies, different objects may be returned based on the specific path of exports that were followed.

This causes problems in some cases, so [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) exist, which allow the top-level of an application to specify a single version of a package, which sub-dependencies share in common.

If every dependency were marked as a `peerDependency`, then a single, global version of each package would exist in an application.

My question is: are there any languages or package managers which enforce a similar behavior everywhere, such that any two packages which share a dependency will share the exact same version of this dependency? And as a bonus, what costs or benefits have said languages/ecosystems encountered as a result of this?

Comment: It is always a trade-off to allow different versions of dependencies vs forcing all dependencies to upgrade. In open-source sometimes your only choice is to fork and maintain your own versions where you upgrade every dependency at your will. A package manager demanding a single version of each component reintroduces what was known as DLL hell in the Windows world.